# ng-include not working, seems to be delayed in requesting the files

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Im having issues using ng-include for templating, I have a sign in page that shows a modal window, the content of which depends on the results of the attempted sign up.

I'm using ng-include to fill in the content of the modal window, like:

```
<div class="md-modal md-effect-10" id="loginModal">
    <div class="md-content">
        <h3 ng-include = "loginTemplate.header"></h3>
        <div ng-include = "loginTemplate.body"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

the success function of my ajax sign in request looks like:

```
$scope.launchModal = function (respStr){
   $scope.loginTemplate = {
      header : "templates/loginModal/"+respStr+"/header.html",
      body   :"templates/loginModal/"+respStr+"/body.html"
   };
   $('#loginModal').addClass('md-show');
};
```

however whats happening is that the window is getting show with nothing in the templates, and only when I dismiss the window do the templates get requested. Then if i show the window again by typing:

```
$('#loginModal').addClass('md-show');
```

the templated content is there.

You can see it in action at the link below, youll need to click "sign up" the login logic isnt hooked up yet.

Any clue?﻿

Answer (score 0):

The problem is when your `modal` showing, your pages `header.html` and `body.html` are not available because there'll be little delay to `GET` the page from server.

Any kind of `HTML` manipulation you need a [directive](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive). So use a directive to show your modal 
In `HTML`

```
<div my-modal class="md-effect-10" id="loginModal">
    <div class="md-content">
        <h3 ng-include = "loginTemplate.header"></h3>
        <div ng-include = "loginTemplate.body"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And `myModal` directive

```
myApp.directive('myModal', function() {
    return {          
      link: function(scope, element) {
        element.addClass('md-show');
      }
    }
  })
```